# Non-existence of a smooth map from $S^2$ with constant rank $1$

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

I have heard lately that there is no smooth map from $S^2$ to any manifold that has constant rank $1$.

The proof for that claim is supposed to be based on the fact that 
the tangent bundle of $S^2$ is irreducible.

However, I do not know what irreducible means in this context and how the implication follows (I searched).

Any help?

Comment: Irreducible likely means no proper subbundle (equivalently can be written as the Whitney sum of proper subbundles). The kernel of the differential of the map would be a proper subbundle of $TS^2$. As the kernel is 1-dimensional and $S^2$ admits no non-orientable subbundles as $H^1(S^2)=0$, such a map would contradict the hairy ball theorem.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it has something to do with the kernel and the hairy ball theorem. The naive idea I had was to show we can choose smoothly a non-zero basis for the kernel at each point, i.e a non-zero vector field in the kernel, but I am not sure how to show this is possible. Can you say why would the kernel be orientable?

Comment: If you want an easier proof of orientability using a stronger condition you can use the fact that $\pi_1(S^2)=0$. Then if $V$ is a non-orientable vector bundle over $S^2$, $V$ is non-orientable as a manifold. But as $V$ deformation retracts onto $S^2$, $V$ is simply connected so it is orientable (as it admits a trivial orientation double cover). Alternatively read a little about the first Stiefel-Whitney class.

Comment: It's probably obvious to you that a orientable vector bundle of rank 1 admits a nonzero section, but I'll comment that anyway.

Comment: @PVAL-inactive: You should make this an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line bundle $E$ over a simply-connected manifold $N$ must be trivial. One way to see this is to choose a metric on $E$ and a metric connection $\nabla$. The connection must be flat (because $E$ is one-dimensional) and has no monodromy because $N$ is simply connected so the parallel transport maps $P_{p,q} \colon E_p \rightarrow E_q$ (where you can choose any path connecting $p$ and $q$) give us an isomorphism between $N \times E_p$ and $E$.

In your case, if $f \colon S^2 \rightarrow M$ is a smooth map of constant rank one, the kernel $\ker(df)$ must be a trivial line subbundle of $TS^2$ so you have a non-vanishing vector field on $S^2$, a contradiction.